# Rename total.js to totaljs

Tags: javascript, node.js, total.js

Is there any problem if I change the name of total.js folder to totaljs, or I have to change some 'require' references?

Example:
Rename Node_modules/total.js to node_modules/totaljs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any problem to rename it. It will work, but you have to change the reference in `require()` to `totaljs`.